# Angular2 - are child routes using an exported constant no longer supported?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using Angular 2.2.3, I have a folder/file structure like this:

```
/proposals
index.ts <- exports everything inside '/proposals'
proposals.routes.ts

/proposals/proposal-document/ProposalDocumentComponent.ts
/proposals/component2
/proposals/component3 etc.
```

The contents of proposals.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProposalDocumentComponent } from './';

export const PROPOSAL_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: ':id/document', component: ProposalDocumentComponent }
]
```

Inside my `app-routing.module.ts` I import the constant and use it like this:

```
import { PROPOSAL_ROUTES } from './proposals';

const routes: Routes = [
...lots of routes..
{ path: 'proposals', component: ProposalsComponent, children: PROPOSAL_ROUTES },
]
```

This throws the error "Error: Outlet is not activated"

Is this no longer supported?